# Checking that two numbers incremented with different values will eventually have the same value

Tags: modular-arithmetic, least-common-multiple

The root of the question is from a hackerrank task but at the end it's a mathematical problem which I don't understand. So the idea is that you have two kangaroos one starting from position `x1` and the other starting from position `x2`. We know for sure that `x2 > x1`. The question is, given that the length of the jump of the first kangaroo is `v1` and the second is `v2` will the kangaroos eventually be at the same spot at the same time.
  My approach was to increment both `x1` and `x2` until they became equal or `x1` gets greater than `x2` which logically works but turns out to be a slower solution. After that I've checked other solutions and it turned out that this check:

> (x2 - x1) % (v1 - v2) == 0

actually is enough. If the modulus is equal to zero then they'll meet, otherwise - they won't. I would appreciate if someone explains in more details why this actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the positions of the kangaroos as a function of time, which I'll call $p_1(t)$ and $p_2(t)$. Note $t$ here is the number of time steps, which must be an integer. At each time step, kangaroo 1 moves by a distance $v_1$, so after $t$ steps, it has moved a distance $t\ v_1$. This gives us a simple linear equation for each kangaroo:

$$p_1(t) = x_1 + v_1 t$$

$$p_2(t) = x_2 + v_2 t$$

To determine if they meet, we need to find an integer $t$ such that $p_1(t) = p_2(t)$. This equation can be easily solved algebraically without imposing the limitation that $t$ be an integer:

$$x_1 + v_1 t = x_2 + v_2 t$$

$$v_1 t - v_2 t = x_2 - x_1$$

$$t = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{v_1 - v_2}$$

This will find the real solution for $t$, provided it exists. In order for this solution to be an integer, $x_2 - x_1$ must be divisible by $v_1 - v_2$. There are a number of ways of checking this condition; one simple one is to check that the remainder of the division is zero, which can be expressed as $(x_2 - x_1) \% (v_1 - v_2) = 0$, since $a\%b$ is by definition the remainder of $\frac ab$.

Note that this includes negative solutions for $t$; If we want to exclude these, we need to check that $v_1 > v_2$, which assures that the first kangaroo will eventually catch up.

Comment: That was the explanation I was looking for, pretty similar to the one of `florence` but I'll accept yours because the addition of the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

We actually need the added condition that $v_1>v_2$, along with the modulus being zero.

The kangaroos will eventually be at the same point if there exists a natural number $n$ such that
$$x_1+nv_1=x_2+nv_2$$
Assuming such $n$ exists, then it must be equal to
$$n = \frac{x_2-x_1}{v_1-v_2}$$
So we can see that $x_2-x_1$ must be a multiple of $v_1-v_2$. Further, since $c_2-x_1>0$, we have that $v_1-v_2>0$. Conversely, if this ratio is an integer and if $v_1>v_2$, then we can see that the first equation is solved for some positive $n$, and so the kangaroos meet.

Comment: Really good answer. Thanks a lot for the clarification, it's basically the same as the one provided from `Kajelad` but since he included the modulus part that was bugging me, I'll accept his answer, still your's is really appreciated and upvoted from me!

Answer (score 0):

The kangaroos will meet if and only if there exists $t$ such that $x_1+tv_1 = x_2+tv_2$, which means that $x_1-x_2=t(v_2-v_1)$, which means that $x_2-x_1 = 0 [v_1-v_2]$.